# RAM store binary numbers and bubble sort in assembly language

Tags: assembly, binary, arm, bubble-sort, armv7

I have to do a routine using ARM v7 that store in RAM memory 10 binary numbers and then sort these numbers from high to low using bubble sort, how should I start?

Comment: Where shall I start? The register file? AAPCS? stack push and pop? loop construct?

Comment: This isn't even a question, it's just a statement.  If you added a "tell me how", it would be too broad.  [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: "How should I start" is not any better.  We don't know how much you do/don't know, so all we can say is write it in C and debug the algorithm, then implement that in asm.  If you make an attempt and provide a [mcve] when you get stuck debugging with a debugger (like GDB) then this could be a debugging question.

Comment: @PeterCordes would you please vote for reopening? I just a wrote an optimized routine that will drive his professor nuts. Aren't you curious? :-)

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE: Sure, if you want to post it here.  The other ARM BubbleSort Q&As I found are debugging questions, so this is probably the best place.

Comment: @PeterCordes Done. I hope you enjoy it. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.func
bubbleSortAscendingU32:
    ldr     r3, [r0], #4
    mov     r1, #9*4
    mov     r12, #9*4
1:
    ldr     r2, [r0], #4
    cmp     r2, r3
    strdlo  r2, r3, [r0, #-8]
    movhi   r3, r2
    subs    r12, r12, #4
    bgt     1b

    sub     r0, r0, r1
    subs    r1, r1, #4
    ldrgt   r3, [r0, #-4]
    movgt   r12, r1
    bgt     1b

    bx      lr
.endfunc
```

Assuming we are dealing with an array of `uint32_t`, that above might work.

both `strdlo` and `movhi` have to be replaced for other types:

Unsigned Descending:
`strdhi` and `movlo`

Signed Ascending:
`strdlt` and `movgt`

Signed Descending:
`strdgt` and `movlt`

The function prototype:

`void bubbleSortAscendingU32(uint32_t *pSrc);`

`void bubbleSortDescendingU32(uint32_t *pSrc);`

`void bubbleSortAscendingS32(int32_t *pSrc);`

`void bubbleSortDescendingS32(int32_t *pSrc);`

---

- Do not ask me for details. I'd have to write half a book for the explanations. Follow the instructions step by step until you finally understand the flow.
- Your professor will most probably need quite some time until he understands the routine above.
- I doubt he will believe that you wrote this by yourself. Be honest.

Comment: Neat.  Predicated stores are fun.  [Sort an Integer List](//codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/149038) on codegolf.SE has a couple x86 asm versions optimized for code-size with evil tricks like memory-destination rotate to swap.  (One of them is a JumpDown sort, a kind of cross between Selection and Bubble Sort.)   [Bubble Sort: An Archaeological Algorithmic Analysis](https://users.cs.duke.edu/~ola/papers/bubble.pdf) is also a good read, on why BubbleSort got popular even though it's usually so slow.